# How to know from which jsp page is calling the servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm doing a project using jsp pages and servlets.

In my servlet I need to identify which jsp page is doing the request.

How can I do this?

Comment: What kind of request? An external request from the browser or some internal include/dispatch ?

Comment: In the jsp page I have a form which is doing a post in a web page @Thilo

Comment: You can read referer attribute on the request but it cannot be safe. Read first solution on this question for more options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791109/request-getheaderreferer-than-back-button-reload-the-page

Comment: may be using sendRequest

Comment: You could look at the `Referer` HTTP header. But it is better to try to avoid having to do this. The information could be spoofed so don't rely on it for anything important. Do you really need to know?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info (in other words, tell which problem you're actually trying to solve for which you most likely incorrectly thought that this would be the correct solution)

Comment: The comment should really be an edit to the question, because the question is hard to understand without it.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to identify the form from which the request come from would be to add a hidden field containing a form identifier. But this is a very uncommon requirement: if you post to same URL, it normally means that the origine of the post does not matter. If it matters (why?), the difference should be in posted data (hence the proposal of a hidden field), or you should post to different URLs. Servlet are not so expensive that you need to limit their number.

Comment: It matters because i have different jsp pages and everyone has a custom form and I need to manage them only with  one servlet (Not my decision, if it was for me I would create a servlet for every page but the exercise say to use only one). So when it comes a request I need to know which jsp pages or form generated that! Btw I've found my solution :) thank u all!

Comment: @untruste Well, you should know which form to expect depending on the user sending you the data, corrrect ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution.

I set a name to the submit button.

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="button1">
```

and then in the servlet I check with

```
String r = request.getParameter("button");
```

Doing that I know from where the request came from

Answer (score 1):

For your servlet, i suppose you are using doGet/doPost to handle request and return response, then in your request from jsp, you can always add a hidden input field to let your servlet know which jsp you come from as follow:

In your jsp:

add a new hidden input textfield:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="jspname" value="jspname" />
```

In your Servlet:

use getparameter method for doPost or getQueryString() for doGet:

in doPost:

```
String jspname = request.getParameter("jspname");
```

By making use of the jspname String, you can easily find out which jsp it is using.

Answer (score 0):

Using `hidden input` is solution in other answers. But you can do that without `hidden input`.

```
    String referer = new URI(request.getHeader("referer")).getPath();
```

`referer` String gives you full `URI`. Additionally for getting `jsp` page name you can use `java code`.

```
    String[] uriNames = referer.split("/");
    String jspPageName = uriNames[uriNames.length-1];
```

Also with `regex` you can get `jsp` page name.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(\\.)(jsp)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
    String jspPageName = "";
    while(matcher.find()) {
         jspPageName = matcher.group();
    }
```